# Gson deserializg single object

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson

I have json object:

```
{
    user:
    {
        id: 1
        avatar_url: "default.png"
        first_name: "Example"
        last_name: "User"
        email: "user@example.com"
    }
}
```

and how can I deserialize this object by GSON having only class:

```
public class User {
    public long id;
    public String avatar_url;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String email;
}
```

Is it possible NOT creating new class ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gson lets you deserialize fields into simple HashMaps. You can do the following in your parent object:

```
@SerializedName("user") HashMap<String, String> user;
...
public String getFirstName() {
    return (user != null) ? user.get("first_name");
}

public Long getId() {
    if (user != null && user.containsKey("id")) {
        return Long.valueOf(user.get("id"));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

(If I understood well,) You can create an instance of the `User` Class from the **json**, you need to define a **builder**:

```
public static User deserializeFromJson(final String userAsJson) throws JsonSyntaxException {

        return new Gson().fromJson(userAsJson, User.class);
}
```

and implement it like:

....
some where if another class.

```
String userJson = .... //get the json from somewhere
try{
User myJsonUser = User.deserializeFromJson(userJson);
....
```

Comment: unfortunetly it works only for structure:
`{
        id: 1,
        avatar_url: "default.png",
        first_name: "Example",
        last_name: "User",
        email: "user@example.com",
    }`